# How to call calling a function inside a Template literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, template-literals

How can I go about calling a function inside a [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

The function syntax in the attempt below shows in the HTML:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        var html = `
        <div class="row">
        ${reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#image_upload_preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }}
        <img id="image_upload_preview" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="your image" />
        </div>
        `;

        $("#test").append(html);

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#multi-file").change(function () {
    readURL(this);
});
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to define and invoke the function inside the template literal.

**Some background**:

You can execute an expression in the template literal as follows:

```
function fun(){
   return 5
}

var someLit=`some function got a value ${fun()}`
```

So this is the simplest and best usage of a function inside literal. Now what you are trying to do in your example is, evaluate the expression

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
  $('#image_upload_preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
}
```

inside the template literal, this binds and event for onload, but the returned value for `reader.onload` is replaced in that position inside the template literal.

and you see `function(){...` in the output.

If you don't want to see that function declaration in the output you can immediately invoke the function.

Example:

```
   (reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#image_upload_preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
   })();
```

This will return undefined in the place of the expression. Now if you want to avoid that `undefined`, you can return some empty string from your function.

```
  (reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#image_upload_preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
      return '';
   })();
```

Now, as you have used this function as an callback for event, immediately invoking the function might not help(as you will not get the e parameter there).

So you can bind the event inside another function like:

```
(function(){
    reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('#image_upload_preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
       }
    return '';
})();
```

this will declare the function, which is bind to your `onload` event and would not leave a trace in your template literal.

**Note:**

Simply declaring the function outside the template literal and calling it inside literal wherever you want is the best option

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can call a function inside a template literal..

```
function something() { 
    return "better than nothing"; 
}
console.log(`Something is ${something()}.`);
//=> Something is better than nothing.
```

Comment: Can you include javascript methods, eg `var my_text = "hello world"; var my_string = \` Here is a great phrase without the first letter:  ${my_text.substring(1)}\``?

Comment: Hmm, for reference, you can do something like this too:  `var dialog_message = \`<p>The cookie's value is "${Cookies.get("page_title")}"</p>\ \``.  This would return something like:  `The cookie's value is "home_page"`.