# Calling a function as a parameter in a template call in Play

Tags: scala, templates, playframework, twirl, play-templates

In Play/Scala; I am confused as to why this won't compile:

```
   @(tabNames: Seq[String])

   @isActive(idx: Int) = {
       @if(idx < 1) {
           "active"
       } else {
           ""
       }
   }

   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       @for((tab, idx) <- tabNames.zipWithIndex) {
           @views.html.generic.navLi("tab" + idx.toString, tab, isActive(idx))
       }
   </ul>
```

The error reads:

> found   : play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable [error]     (which
>   expands to)  play.twirl.api.Html [error]  required: String [error]
>   @views.html.generic.navLi("tab" + idx.toString, tab, isActive(idx))

It doesn't recognise the call to `isActive` within the call to the template and I have tried multiple variations, e.g. `@isActive(idx)`, `isActive(@idx)` `${isActive(idx)}` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963168/how-to-call-calling-a-function-inside-a-template-literal)), etc. This template generates a navigation bar, passing in tab names and checking to see if the `nav li` should be `active` (configured by class name/JS).

It just seems that the syntax must be different when calling a function within another template call - I can't get it right.

Answer (score 4):

[Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates#Declaring-reusable-blocks) makes a distinction between

- reusable code block
- reusable **pure** code block

Note the subtle difference in `@` usage between

```
@isActive(idx: Int) = {
  @if(...

@isActive(idx: Int) = @{
  if(...
```

Reusable pure code block can have arbitrary return type. In your case, to have `String` as return type, you could write:

```
   @isActive(idx: Int) = @{
       if(idx < 1) {
           "active"
       } else {
           ""
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Play documentation is a little light in this area](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates#Declaring-reusable-blocks); while it is certainly possible and useful to declare "functions" in a twirl template, the return type seems to be locked to (effectively) `Html` - i.e. your "block" (as it is referred to in the documentation) must render HTML.

The quickest solution, as suggested in the documentation, is to relocate the logic into a Scala class; for something as simple as this, an `object` is the easiest way to get this done, i.e.:

```
package views

object ViewHelper {

  def isActive(idx: Int):String = {
    if(idx < 1) {
      "active"
    } else {
      ""
    }
  }
}
```

and:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   @for((tab, idx) <- tabNames.zipWithIndex) {
       @views.html.generic.navLi("tab" + idx.toString, tab, ViewHelper.isActive(idx))
   }
</ul>
```

The advantages of this approach include testability and reusability. Just be careful to avoid getting carried away with what a `ViewHelper` can do - database lookups etc are a bad idea here! :-)

Comment: Yes - the documentation definitely is *light* on this topic. Are you sure that the `views` package is the best place to put this `object`? Also I noticed that you didn't import `ViewHelper` - is this right? thanks

Comment: By placing it in `views` I don't __need__ to import it :-)